# Ecommerce system for EE and requesting a quote

Tags: expresso-store, ee2, cartthrob, brilliantretail

I need customers to submit a quote rather than an order, which as i understand is easy to do just use a manual payment gateway, but the bit I'm not sure on is the admin needs to login in & update product prices and delivery cost for the order then sends this out in an email?

Is this do-able? and which extension would you recommend?

Comment: Just a word of warning on Cartthrob: their parent company Mighty Big Robot seems to be closing for good and they will no longer support any of their products from this point forward.  It seems pretty abrupt, and I'm not sure what the circumstances are but you can see some details on their website: http://cartthrob.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can use BrilliantRetail to generate 'quotes' instead of orders. The quote request would be emailed to admins and the customer. From that point though you would need to handle the actual pricing outside of BrilliantRetail.

You can add order notes to the quote that the client would see but currently you can't edit the line item details to add pricing.

Please let me know if you have any other questions!

Comment: thanks, that might be the way to go, I really need to be able to manage the prices and delivery, do you know if Carthrob or expresso store allow that?